# Creating a Spring '20 Preview scratch org not working?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, spring-20

Based on this information [Select the Salesforce Release for a Scratch Org](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_scratch_orgs_version_selection.htm):

```
Release Version   Preview Start Date    Preview End Date
Winter ’20        September 6, 2019     October 12, 2019
Spring ’20        January 3, 2020       February 15, 2020
Summer ’20        May 8, 2020           June 13, 2020
```

I am surprised to get:

> At this time, we are outside of the preview period. You can create
>   only current release scratch orgs.

when trying to create a `"release": "Preview"` scratch org.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug at this point

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/260

From the Twitter conversations with PM, he is aware of it and they are working on it to fix it asap.

Current workaround is [sign up](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring20/) for a prerelease org and then enable devhub and use that to create spring 20 scratch orgs.

**Update**

Update from PM that this has been fixed now!

Comment: Thanks for this Mohith and the workaround.

Comment: They are supposed to release the patch with fix today. Will update here once I see it fixed

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed now as per PM Twitter reply.